# Hide scrolled content under fixed transparent header bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've seen some similar q's but the solutions weren't working possibly because I'm using bootstrap. The body of my page is a gradient of two colors running vertically. The header is fixed and should be adopting the corresponding color of the gradient. Thus I made it transparent. I would like to hide all elements going under the header.

**html**

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" >
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
  <h1 id="home-h1"><a href="index.html">title</a></h1>

  </div>
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">navitem</a></li>
      <li><a href="#navitem">navitem</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
```

**css**

```
 body {

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#99DAD2, #FEECA4);
    background: linear-gradient(#99DAD2, #FEECA4);
}

 .navbar-default {
    /* navbar background color */
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

Comment: Nice quest .. I've made this example http://www.bootply.com/6NxonCPj1c .. I think it isn't possible with CSS and you may need JS, but love to see if any can answer this with just CSS

Comment: @DaniP thx - yea i think that the fixed header is achieved in Strap w/ JS so I'm guessing that a JS solution is needed.